# Opengl 2.0 How to apply texture to triangle?

Tags: android, opengl-es

How would I apply a texture to a triangle. Just a basic summary of how to do it will do. I already know how to draw one to a square so how different would it be to a triangle instead. I am using android btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is actually no difference at all. A rectangle is composed of 2 triangles so what you are asking is the same thing as drawing half of the rectangle where you already know how to draw a whole one.

Most of the objects in openGL are drawn only with triangles. The texture on them is defined through the texture coordinates and the image from which the texture is loaded can be very strange. Try searching the web images for "model texture" to see what I mean.

The reason why I am explaining this is because I believe you need to start thinking about the texture and the coordinates the other way around as you do now. The texture coordinates are actually just relative positions on the texture which represent what part of the texture should be drawn between the points the shape is bound to. So the texture for a rectangle will most likely look like a plain image since the plain image already is a rectangle. For a sphere for instance the texture will already look quite strange since you need to somehow represent all the points on the sphere on a 2d surface, usually a rectangle.

So to draw a textured triangle you need position coordinates and texture coordinates. A most simple example can be:

```
float vertexData[] = {
0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0,
100.0, 0.0, 0.0,
1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 100.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0
};
```

And this is the same as for the rectangle but missing the last coordinate:

```
100.0, 100.0, 0.0,
1.0, 1.0
```

Still these texture coordinates can be anything you want for your texture. You simply need to compute the relative texture coordinate position.